# Can't put string into another string to restart loop

Tags: php

I need help with a problem where I need to perform xor operation among the characters of the string. However once the loop concludes, I want to start the loop again  and perform on the newly created string.
This means that when the loop reaches the end, I want put `$newStr`into `$str`, then restart the loop so that I can perform exor operation on the new string created from the previous loop

Eg: 
string : 10101

1st iteration:1111

2nd:000

3rd:00

final:0

I have tried putting an if condition wherein `if $i==$len-2`, put `$newStr` into `$str` and continue at the end of the condition

```
for ($i=0; $i < $len-1; $i++) {
    $a = (int)$str[$i];
    $b = (int)$str[$i+1];
    $c = $a ^ $b;
    $newStr .= $c;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean repeat the above code until some condition.  If so you could wrap it in a `while()` loop and copy the string after the `for()` loop has finished back.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$str = '10101';
echo "{$str}\n";

while ( ($len = strlen($str)) > 1 ) {
    $newStr = '';
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $len - 1; $i++ ) {
        $a      = (int)$str[$i];
        $b      = (int)$str[$i + 1];
        $c      = $a ^ $b;
        $newStr .= $c;
    }
    $str = $newStr;
    echo "{$str}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
10101
1111
000
00
0
```